# Delete flow definition in prefect orion

Tags: python, prefect

How do I delete a flow defined in `prefect orion`? For example, I have multiple flows visible in the Orion's dashboard, some of which are no longer useful for me. How do I delete some (but not all) flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this at the moment is through the REST API: https://orion-docs.prefect.io/api-ref/orion/api/flows/#prefect.orion.api.flows.delete_flow

It has yet to be hooked up to the UI.